# Space after lettrine

Tags: spacing, microtype, lettrine, drop-cap

When using the `lettrine` package, there are often additional spaces after the small caps:

[image: space after small caps]

It can get even bigger than that actually. It seems to me that this is because `lettrine` uses an `mbox` to prevent breaking the line, so the spaces inside the `mbox` are not modified properly.

Is that the case, and how can I get more equilibrated spaces after the small caps?

**Note:**

Even when only one word is used in the lettrine, the problem still shows up:[image: using one word only]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had made myself a wrapper for the `\lettrine` command to override the default values. After reading the `lettrine` manual again, I found out that it was better to override the length in a local `lettrine.cfg` file.

Then, to override the settings for each letter, I used `\LettrineOptionsFor` instead of personal macros. These go in a special file as defined by the `\DefaultOptionsFile` command in `lettrine.cfg` (that gets quite complex).

These two steps solved my problem.

For example, my `lettrine.cfg` contains:

```
\setcounter{DefaultLines}{3}                                                    
%%                                                                              
%% These are *decimal* numbers:                                                 
\renewcommand{\DefaultLoversize}{0.25}                                          
\renewcommand{\DefaultLraise}{0}                                                
\renewcommand{\DefaultLhang}{0.33}                                              
% Define default options per letter                                             
\renewcommand{\DefaultOptionsFile}{optfile.cfl}
```

and then `optfile.cfl` contains:

```
% options per letter                                                            
\LettrineOptionsFor{A}{slope=5pt,findent=-0.5em}                                
\LettrineOptionsFor{J}{lraise=0.20,nindent=0em}                                 
\LettrineOptionsFor{L}{lraise=0,loversize=0.08,findent=-0.9em,nindent=1em}      
\LettrineOptionsFor{P}{findent=0.1em,nindent=0.1em}                             
\LettrineOptionsFor{Q}{lraise=0.30,loversize=0.15}
```

The result for my example is:

[image: lettrine with proper spacing]

Answer (score 2):

`\lettrine`'s second argument is supposed to be just one word. If you want two like your example, use `\textsc` explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage[margin=3in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\lettrine Q{uel} \textsc{est} le travail de l'Esprit Comme nous
l'avons d\'ej\`a not lateur, etc.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That doesn't change the problem. The first word still has an additional space after it (see the new screenshot in the question).

Comment: @Raphink: You should post the code that produces that. I don't get that at all.

Comment: The problem seems to come from a macro of mine which overrides `\lettrine`. I'm debugging it now. Thanks.